# Listbox-like xml element in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to create a program that has an element like the windows forms list box, but I don't know what to use or how to do it.

```
ListBox.Items.Add("Something");
```

But how would I do this in Android? Just simple lines of strings each time.

Comment: What about a ListView?  You can find information on how to implement here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_1_-_listview_parts_and_functionality/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent control exactly like ListBox,
 
But you can use the [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/)  And you can customize appearance to look like ListBox (you can put it in [Linear Layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/linear_layout/))

Or you can create  [custom Adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/)

Useful ListView topic:

- [Android ListViews Reinvented](http://sharpmobilecode.com/android-listviews-reinvented/)
- [ListView Example in Xamarin.Android](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/xamarin/listview-example-in-xamarin-android)

Some UI controls component can help you :

- [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)
- [monodroid-samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples)
- [Xamarin-Templates](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/tree/master/Xamarin.Android-Templates)

Comment: he is not using XF

Comment: Xamarin.Android

Comment: thanks @Jason I have edit my answer ,@ThatGuy the ListBox also doesn't   exist in Xamarin.Android

Comment: the only ListBox control in Xamarin in System.Windows.Forms.ListBox https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Windows.Forms.ListBox/

Answer (score 0):

use a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) control ([Xamarin sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/))

Comment: No not like that. I was using my listbox like a log of my stuff, but not as a drop down. It is not used for selecting things, just for showing them.

Comment: Then use a ListView